# Uploading to mySQL and using SimpleImage PHP?

Tags: php, mysql

I'm hoping this is an easy one, I'm using mySQL and php to upload an image as a BLOB type using this code:

```
if(isset($_POST['upload']) && $_FILES['userfile']['size'] > 0)
    {

    $fileName = $_FILES['userfile']['name'];    
    $tmpName  = $_FILES['userfile']['tmp_name'];
    $fileSize = $_FILES['userfile']['size'];
    $fileType = $_FILES['userfile']['type'];

    $fp      = fopen($tmpName, 'r');
    $content = fread($fp, filesize($tmpName));
    $content = addslashes($content);
    fclose($fp);

    if(!get_magic_quotes_gpc())
    {
        $fileName = addslashes($fileName);
    }
```

This is all working fine, inserting to the database and everything. I then want to use SimpleImage: `http://www.white-hat-web-design.co.uk/blog/resizing-images-with-php/` to perform some resize and compression work on the image before uploading it. I can't see how to combine say:

```
include('SimpleImage.php');
      $image = new SimpleImage();
      $image->load($_FILES['userfile']['tmp_name']);
      $image->resizeToWidth(150);
      $image->output();
```

With my existing code, I think what I want to do is get $content to become $image, but I've tried for a while and can't find a way of doing it. Any help much appreciated.

Happy Christmases to those who like Christmas and TIA to all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are outputting the resized image to the browser (`::output()`) but you're not saving it. If you want to store it inside the database, you need to change the temporary file first, e.g. by using the `::save()` function of `SimpleImage`.

Next to that, you write you want to resize the picture in the browser before uploading. That can not be done with PHP, but only with javascript and browsers who support that. Additionally the upload handling on the PHP side might differ then. But I'm not really sure if you really meant it that the image is resized *before* uploading.

Another Idea I had is using an output buffer:

```
if (isset($_POST['upload']) && $_FILES['userfile']['size'] > 0)
{    
    $fileName = $_FILES['userfile']['name'];    
    $tmpName  = $_FILES['userfile']['tmp_name'];
    $fileSize = $_FILES['userfile']['size'];
    $fileType = $_FILES['userfile']['type'];
    $image = new SimpleImage();
    $image->load($_FILES['userfile']['tmp_name']);
    $image->resizeToWidth(150);
    ob_start();
    $image->output();
    $content = ob_get_clean();

    $content = addslashes($content);
    ...
```

Comment: save it as temporary image then do the resize etc to it, it that what your saying?

Comment: Well if it's a file-upload you have the temporary file already, so probably you can reuse it (PHP might not allow that, but if I were you I would test if it works). So resize `$_FILES['userfile']['tmp_name']` and save it to the same filename. Or, use an output buffer and `output()`, then get the buffers content into `$content` instead of reading the tempfile.

Comment: TY I'll give it a whirl and let you know!

Comment: Got it working, will give the buffer a go as well now. Thanks.